# How to implement captcha on joomla administrator panel?

Tags: php, joomla

i need help on topic. I am using Joomla 2.5 for some security reason i need catcha on joomla administrator login panel. How i can implement it? Is there any extension available for it. i have tried it but Joomla session is created after the login of account. So it can not pass the value at time of login. Please help with possible solution

Comment: Here you go: http://precisionsec.com/protect-your-admin-panel-against-password-attacks-using-a-captcha/

Answer (score 0):

A third-party extenion jSecure Authentication allows you to  add extra security layer to Joomla! administration area. You can download the plugin from http://www.joomlaserviceprovider.com/component/ambrasubs/file/view/5/7.html.

Once installed the plugin, follow the steps below:

1. From Joomla! administration panel, click Extensions | Plugin Manager. That shows Plugin Manager screen listing all installed plugins. From the list, click on System – jSecure Authentication link. That shows Plugin:[Edit] screen for the plugin.
2. Select Yes in Enabled field.
3. In Plugin Parameters section, type a secret key in Key field.
4. Check Redirect to index page in Redirect Options field.
5. Click Save button in the toolbar.
6. Now preview the site by clicking on Preview button. Type admin panel’s URL in the address bar. You will be redirected to home page of the site.
7. For accessing the administration panel, add the secret key at the end of the URL. For example, http://www.yourdomain.com/administrator/?secretkey.
8. Now you will be able to see the login box for administration area.

Comment: thanks for your concern but basically my website is under security audit. So they have policy you have to implement captcha at every login page :(